# All Equations signs from my document disappeared

Tags: equations

I have used the following packages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}           
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```

All of the equal to sign disappeared from my document. I don't know which packages to add or delete to bring back my equal to sign. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code snippet does not generate the problem you wish to fix. Please augment it to create a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) (MWE) that does let us re-create the problem, so that we may diagnose it and (hopefully) come up with a cure.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. Anyway, the problem is `\usepackage{fourier}` that’s incompatible with the subsequent `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Use either, but not both. By the way, `a4wide` has been deprecated for more that 20 years.